# Tests fail on travis, which pass local

Tags: javascript, ruby, capybara, travis-ci, poltergeist

My tests which turn green local, are getting red on travis. It's about this code:

```
And I change the year to "nineteen-ninenty-seven"                                                                           # features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:9
And I attempt to save the changes                                                                                           # features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:17
Then I should see a message indicating that the data is invalid                                                             # features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:26
  expected to find text "Value must be of type integer." in "Provider configurations root name artist year" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:27:in `/^I should see a message indicating that the data is invalid$/'
  features/editing_resources.feature:52:in `Then I should see a message indicating that the data is invalid'
```

This is in my support/capybara.rb

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.app = App.new
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_wait_time = 10
```

It's about this code:

```
When(/^I change the year to "(.*?)"$/) do |year|
  find('input[name="root[year]"]').set year
end

When(/^I attempt to save the changes$/) do
  find('input[type=submit]')
end

Then(/^I should see a message indicating that the data is invalid$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content('Value must be of type integer.')
end
```

The problem:

When I run the tests local, they turn green. I debugged it there. I'm for sure that the code works well. The fields exist and get filled with the right data. When I use pry in my local tests on the point that I expect the message, I 'source' (or html), and I can find the text myself. On travis/ubuntu this doesn't work. I can confirm this doesn't work, cause I contacted Travis and they gave me a VM for a day where I duplicated the problem.

To solve it, I tried multiple things, I increased waiting time, tried selenium/webkit and selenium with chrome/firefox. They al work local, but I can't get them working properly on travis.

What I want to achieve is that the test validates if the user see's a messages which is getting created when a field isn't filled properly (text in integer field in this example).

The message is created by Json editor. https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor
And looks like this in code:

```
<small class="error">Value must be of type integer.</small>
```

A logic explanation in my opinion: in travis, the dom doesn't get the newest version which should load after an activity get's executed (like fill_in or set) and local this does work.

I hope somebody has an explanation and a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't provide an answer for your exact problem, I can try to help you debug the issue with the information you provided.

Regarding Poltergeist:

[Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#running-on-a-ci) allows you to take screenshots at specific points in your test

> Depending on your tests, one thing that you may need is some fonts. If you're getting errors on a CI that don't occur during development then try taking some screenshots

I would try using `page.save_screenshot` before and after the points you identified and see what the differences are between local/travis.

EDIT: There is also a gem for capybara that takes screenshots whenever a test fails. Find more info here: [Capybara-Screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot)